# Bean Creation failing after adding security jars

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am experiencing following error

Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userAuditLogAspect': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.vzw.aspect.UserAuditLogAspect.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=topoDataSource)}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'topoDataSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.expression.TypedValue

My web xml is :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-security.xml, WEB-INF/topoService-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- Spring Security Filter -->
 <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <!-- <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vz.myrest.MessageRestService</param-value>
    </context-param> -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>}
```

2) toposervice-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    >   
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vzw.context, com.vzw.aspect, com.vzw.logger" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="topoDataSource" jndi-name="java:/TopoDSJNDI" />

    <!--<bean class="com.vzw.context.SpringApplicationContext"></bean> -->

    <bean id="topoServiceDao" class="com.vzw.topo.dao.TopoServiceDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="topoDataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

3) pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId> <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security ends -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Issue is as soon as I add the security dependency I get the exception. It has something to do with context But I am not sure.
Any pointer would be helpful.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your Spring dependencies have version `3.1.1.RELEASE` others have `3.1.2.RELEASE` or `3.1.3.RELEASE`. Use the same Spring version throughout. You should define a `spring.version` property in your maven pom rather than entering the values manually.

Check the classpath your application runs with (e.g. running the tests with `mvn -X`) and make sure there are no inconsistencies such as different Spring jar versions or duplicate jars with different version numbers.